# List of file modified and commited in SVN since last build in Jenkins

Tags: shell, svn, ant, build, jenkins

In my project, during the start of our qa build we execute "svn status --show-updates" command on the unix console to display all the differences in the file structure of the current working directory versus the SVN repository.

Now i am trying to migrate our build process to Jenkins and wondering how to achieve it using an Ant script or any other way.

Please advise.

Comment: Jenkins keeps track of this in the "Recent Changes" link it creates for each build, is that enough for you ?

Comment: Thanks nos, is there a way we can read this through script and send it  in an email as its body?

Comment: Yes... you want to check out the https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin  the default templates have decent looking html changelists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jenkins can run shell scripts as build steps.  Just click the "Add build step" dropdown and select "Execute shell".

Alternatively, if you want this to be executed within Ant for some reason, you could just use the exec task:

```
<exec dir="${basedir}" executable="svn" >
    <arg line="status --show-updates" />
</exec>
```